# application.html.erb not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, rendering

My goal is to render a view with `app/layouts/application.html.erb` as layout from a nested controller `Shared::ResourceController#show`.

An overview of my controller would be like

```
app/controllers
├── application_controller.rb
├── calendars_controller.rb
├── events_controller.rb
├── shared
│   ├── base_controller.rb
│   ├── resources_controller.rb
```

In `Shared::BaseController`, I've a service which identifies resources. The controller then sets some instance variable such as `@resource` (which could be a calendar or an event).

I want everything that inherits this controller to render its view within `app/view/layouts/application.html.erb`, so:

```rb
# app/controllers/shared/base_controller.rb
module Shared
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    layout :application
  end
end

# app/controllers/shared/resources_controller.rb  
module Shared
  class ResourcesController < BaseController
    def show
      render @resource
    end
  end
end
```

The layout includes a simple `yield`:

```html
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb  -->
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the rendered view renders some partials:

```html
<!-- app/views/shared/calendars/_calendar.html.erb -->
<%= render partial: './calendars/calendar_sidebar', locals: { calendar: @resource } %>
<%= render partial: './calendars/calendar' %>
```

but, as per the log (and the look), the layout is not rendered:

```
Started GET "/fr/shared/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-05-31 14:54:50 +0200
Processing by Shared::ResourcesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"fr", "token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  Calendar Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "ef12946f-de9f-4884-88d1-d9013786cf3c"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/services/jwt/identify_resource_service.rb:15:in `execute'
  Rendered ./calendars/_calendar_sidebar.html.erb (Duration: 4.5ms | Allocations: 1192)
  Rendered ./calendars/_calendar.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 116)
  Rendered shared/calendars/_calendar.html.erb (Duration: 8.4ms | Allocations: 1974)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms | Allocations: 3955)
```

---

I'm pretty sure my controller structure is causing issues. Before that I'd specific controllers (per events, calendars, ...), and everything was fine. Now I want some resource agnostic controllers, I'm not able to render the appropriate layout.

Question is, how to structure layout using nested controllers ?
How to render layout A from controller B::B ?

```
app/view
├── A.html.rb

app/controllers
├── B
│   ├── B.rb
```

Comment: Quick thing to try... Should that be `layout "application"`, not `layout :application`? According to [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#choosing-layouts-at-runtime), passing a symbol will call a method to determine the layout at runtime, so that might not be doing what you think it is?

Comment: Yes I did try that, no difference

Comment: OK, well I'm really not sure why that isn't working. There's definitely *some* code you haven't shown us (e.g. what's in `ApplicationController`, or could there even be a `Shared::ApplicationController`?!), and there are probably a few things you could try to debug it (e.g. what happens if you call `render @resource, layout: 'application'`?) Your post is also inconsistent around whether the layout file is defined in `app/view/application.html.erb` or `app/view/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: If you're struggling to pinpoint the root of the problem, could be more helpful by providing a [mcve] of the problem -- ideally so someone could even run `rails new` and quickly replicate the exact same behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: I did reproduce the issue with a minimap application: https://gitlab.com/kawsay/nested_controller_and_layouts

No bugs involved, I must be missing something about `render`. If you create a book and navigate to it (`/nested/books/1`), you'll see that the partial `_book` is rendered, but the layout isn't.


Still, it does help me to understand, thanks !

Comment: you haven't pushed any code to that project, so I can't see it.

Comment: Indeed I misconfigured gitlab. It's ok now

Comment: That code does not use `layout 'application'` anywhere in the controllers. In particular, there is nothing [here](https://gitlab.com/kawsay/nested_controller_and_layouts/-/blob/main/app/controllers/nested/base_controller.rb).

Comment: `layout 'application'` in `Nested::BaseController` does not solve the issue. I pushed this diff

Comment: OK I fixed it. Issue was that `render @resource` renders the partial related to this resource. I replaced it with `render :show, template: "shared/#{@resource_controller}/show"`, which includes the layout: ` Rendering shared/calendars/show.html.erb within layouts/application`.  Thanks for your time anyway, you did help me a lot to think about it

Answer (score 0):

`render @resource` is shorthand for `render partial: @resource.class.name.underscore, object: @resource`.  Ie. it's doing a partial render (from ActionView) not a controller render.  Ie. there's no layout used.

You'd need to change this to something like `render :some_view` which should really be the `:show` view, but could be any view you like, but it needs to be a normal (non-partial) view which then renders the partial inside it.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the extra comments - was going to delete this, but I'll leave it in case others find this question.